# Following stored procedure is not giving any error but its running continuously and not updating or inserting value in table

Tags: mysql

```
BEGIN
  Declare testID int;
  Declare userID int;

  Drop TABLE IF EXISTS temporaryTable;

  CREATE TABLE temporaryTable (
  testID int not null,
  userID int not null, 
  is_submitted int not null
  );

  INSERT INTO temporaryTable(
  testID, 
  userID, 
  is_submitted
  )
  SELECT A.test_id, A.user_id, A.is_submitted FROM
  (
  SELECT `test_id`,`user_id`,
    IF((TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, TU.start_date,NOW()) - ET.duration) > 60,
      1,0) AS is_submitted
FROM tests T
LEFT JOIN test_user TU  ON T.id = TU.test_id
LEFT JOIN exam_templates ET ON T.exam_template_id = ET.id
WHERE is_test_submitted = 0
) AS A
WHERE A.is_submitted = 1;

WHILE EXISTS(
    SELECT testID, userID FROM temporaryTable
    WHERE is_submitted = 1
) Do

SELECT testID, userID INTO @testID, @userID 
FROM temporaryTable 
WHERE is_submitted = 1 Limit 1;


DELETE FROM temporaryTable 
WHERE testID = @testID AND userID = @userID;

UPDATE test_user 
SET is_test_submitted = 1, end_date = NOW()
WHERE testID = @testID AND userID = @userID;

INSERT INTO appeared_tests (test_id,user_id,question_set_id,status)
SELECT @testID, @userID, question_set_id,0 
FROM question_set_test 
WHERE test_id = @testID AND question_set_id NOT IN
(
  SELECT question_set_id 
    FROM appeared_tests
  WHERE user_id = @userID 
      AND test_id = @testID
);

END WHILE;

DROP TABLE temporaryTable;

END
```

Comment: is it in a transaction? do you need to explicity call COMMIT in order to have the update take affect?

Comment: no it is not in transaction,But I'm not sure why this SP not updating data even it not throwing any error